# C# sending email script in SSIS working on machine and not on another

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, ssis

My colleague copied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739984/unable-to-send-mail-from-ssis-using-script-task) to send emails from SSIS using scripts, replaced the emails and variables with our sample gmail address which resulted with the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace ST_24c8cd1fcaa741e9aec2d04071a225c8
{
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sample_sender@gmail.com", "sample_recipient@gmail.com", "subject", "body");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sample_sender@gmail.com", "secret_password");
        client.Send(mail);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
}
```

This solution works fine for him on his machine (not deployed to SQL server) but I receive the following error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

when executing the task. Even if I create a new package and copy his code into my script, it comes back with an error. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: You can set breakpoints inside C# scripts in SSIS too. Have you tried that to hone in on the problematic statement?

Comment: It crashes before this line:
    client.Send(mail);